# qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wayland"

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying to run through some image recognition tutorials, but I keep running into this error that's preventing me from proceeding. I'm running Ubuntu 21.10, and Python 3.9.7. My code is as such.

```
import cv2
img=cv2.imread("path",1)
#print(type(img))
#print(img)
#print(img.shape)
#print(img.ndim)
cv2.imshow("Moon",img)
cv2.waitKey(2000)
```

More importantly, this is the error I get:

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in "/home/peepo/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins"
```

I went to the folder in the path and sure enough, Wayland isn't there. I've been searching around for a while now and installed several different things from solutions to people experiencing similar things I've found on the web. Nothing has worked.

Currently I'm at the point where I'm looking to see if there's some manual download somewhere that I can just drag and drop into the folder. I've read that there are some issues with the new version of Ubuntu and qt4, so I'm not sure if this is more of an Ubuntu or Python problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same issue after upgrading to Ubuntu 21.10 (from 20.10).

Installing an older version of OpenCV worked for me.

```
pip install opencv-python==4.3.0.38
```

Answer (score 21):

I ran into the same problem when trying to launch KeepassXC 2.6.6 with Wayland:

```
QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland keepassxc
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in ""
```

The solution on Ubuntu 21.10 and 22.04 was to install `qtwayland5`:

```
sudo apt install qtwayland5
```

Comment: Same https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1004361

Comment: Hmm.. I have qtwayland5 installed, then also installed qt6-wayland just in case, but both/either resulted in the same error "Could not find the Qt platform plugin 'wayland'" from multiple applications. I tried setting a few env vars that I came across in other posts, etc, but all ended with the same result.

Comment: @MostHated what applications are you running? They may not be qt5/6 apps

Comment: I wish I could remember. I want to say that I did get it figured out, but unfortunately, I can't say for sure. It must not have been *that* important, if I can't even remember what it was, lol. I want to say that the resolution was to use QT_QPA_PLATFORM="wayland;xcb", so that xcb was an automatic fallback in the event of wayland not working for whatever reason.

Answer (score 12):

I encountered a very similar error when trying to start [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/) 27.1.3 on Arch Linux running Sway as the window manager. OBS produced this error:

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in ""
```

[This bug report](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/72972) indicated that I was missing the dependency [`qt5-wayland`](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/qt5-wayland/) which I fixed by installing it:

```
pacman -S qt5-wayland
```

Afterwards, OBS ran just fine and it was able to record the screen and audio.

Comment: This got me in the right direction! For me the missing Arch package was qt6-wayland, since my project was using QT6.

Comment: Just a note for anyone getting this issue with Ubuntu for some reason the v5 version of this lib was called qtwayland5 so you would assume to get the v6 version it would be called qtwayland6 but it's not, it's now called qt6-wayland like Arch.

Answer (score 5):

Latest fix as of 2023 Dec, OBS just moved to qt6 , so installing , any packages related to qt5 will not have any effect , install the `qt6-wayland` package to  solve this issue

Comment: I installed qt6-wayland and no changes. shall I reboot (as in the winzozz machines)?

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu 22, set the system variant in `/etc/environment`:

```
QT_QPA_PLATFORM="xcb"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and installed qtwayland5 but the error remained.  What did solve the problem was using X11 by setting

export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb

(Not running ubuntu though, running fedora 38)

Answer (score 0):

Due to this wayland conflict, screensharing was not working in ubuntu22 on my machine. I fixed that following the steps in this link.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407494/screen-share-not-working-in-ubuntu-22-04-in-all-platforms-zoom-teams-google-m

Following this, I uninstalled and reinstalled opencv-python and every OpenCV feature started working magically. No more wayland conflicts.

Answer (score -2):

My problem for this error was simple

```
sudo chmod 0777 /dev -R
```

Now OBS start without problems